# How to store the file as an array in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I am trying to make a code that reads the lines in file and then store it as an array in scala?

The following is the code I wrote:

```
import scala.io.Source
val fname = args(0)
for (line <- Source.fromFile(fname).getLines)
```

I don't know what to do next?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an array, you simply can call `toArray` on the `getLines` method.

```
val arrayOfLines = Source.fromFile(fname).getLines.toArray
```

(or `.toList` for [an immutable list](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7988))